# How do I set a VB.Net ComboBox default value

Tags: vb.net

I can not locate the correct method to make the first item in a combo box visible.

The app starts with an empty combo box. The user makes a radio box selection then clicks Go! (how original). The combo box is loaded via an LDAP query. All this is working just fine. The problem is the combo box still appears to the user to be empty. They must click the arrow to see the options.

How do I make the first option 'visible' after the users clicks Go!?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
 ' Your code filling the combobox '
 ...

 If myComboBox.Items.Count > 0 Then
     myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0    ' The first item has index 0 '
 End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Just go to the combo box properties - DropDownStyle and change it to "DropDownList"

This will make visible the first item.

Comment: This is good for setting anything other than an empty combo selection without setting having to set it programmatically. Basic but good, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

OR

you can write this down in your program

```
Private Sub ComboBoxExp_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)Handles MyBase.Load
    AlarmHourSelect.Text = "YOUR DEFAULT VALUE"
    AlarmMinuteSelect.Text = "YOUR DEFAULT VALUE"
End Sub
```

so when you start your program, the first thing it would do is set it on your assigned default value and later you can easily select your required option from the drop down list.
also keeping the DropDownStyle to DropDownList would make it look more cooler.

-Starkternate

Answer (score 2):

because you have set index is 0 it shows always 1st value from combobox as input.

Try this :

```
With Me.ComboBox1
    .DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
    .Text = " "
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
Me.cbo1.Text = Me.Cbo1.Items(0).Tostring
```

Answer (score 2):

```
If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0    
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler solution, Select the Combo-box, and in the option of Selected item, select the item index (0 for the first item) and set it to be the default value in the combo box.

Comment: Not sure this is any simpler than the accepted answer, but OK.

Answer (score 0):

Another good method for setting a DropDownList style combobox:

```
Combox1.SelectedIndex = Combox1.FindStringExact("test1")
```