# Set the default value of a ComboBox (DropDownList) in VB 2012

Tags: vb.net

How can I set the default value for a ComboBox (DropDownList) component in Visual Basic 2012?
I'm very new in Visual Basic

Comment: Have you tried something? Add some code to your question. Check  this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on how to write and ask a good question.

Comment: please try to find an answer before posting a question to avoid duplication, Try something like this `If myComboBox.Items.Count > 0 Then myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0 End If`, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637544/how-do-i-set-a-vb-net-combobox-default-value]

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new here. I've tried something like `If myComboBox.Items.Count > 0 Then myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0 End If` but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'default'? You mean the initial value when you load the form?

Comment: Yes. It's something like this http://i.imgur.com/kDiZp.png

Comment: Are you sure you are not calling that statement (as suggested by @Patriks ) **before** any items are actually added to the ComboBox? Because it works for me, with a dummy application.

Comment: myComboBox.Items.Add("UDP") : myComboBox.Items.Add("TCP") : myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0